# How to access many to many model field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
     coverage = models.ManyToManyField('Coverage')
```

And another model

```
class Coverage(models.Model):
      time_needed = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to display time needed for each employee but it list all of them

this is what I have tried

```
{% for employee in employees %}
    {% for coverage in employee.coverage.all %}
           {{ coverage.time_needed }} min
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it iterates through each item. I basically need a way of accesing and displaying the time needed for each employee
Any helpful answer would be appreciated thanks

ps: This is a part of a larger model class

Comment: `for employee in employee`?

Comment: Let me update it

Comment: `{% for coverage in employee.coverage_set.all %}`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It returns blank

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. The code you have posted works fine. You say that it "lists all of them", but that is how a many to many relationship works. If you don't want many coverages for an employee, perhaps you need a foreign key or one to one instead?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah that's true but I want the time_needed per location for each employee

Comment: @DanielRoseman currently it iterates through the whole time needed in the database